# Ubuntu is booting in to emergency mode

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, ubuntu-gnome, boot-repair

Today when i power on the PC, I get error message as follow:

```
Welcome to emergency mode!

After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs
`systemctl 1 reboot` to reboot, 'systemctl 1 default' or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.
```

Yesterday I had run some commands as my file system is not recognizing my pendrive; the commands are as follows

```
sudo su
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -t auto
```

I think this has changed by default boot partition.

Now when i run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

the output is as follows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x366b366a

Device    Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63  62910539  62910477    30G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        62912512  67119543   4207032     2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4        67121150 976768064 909646915 433.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       109065348 119555729  10490382     5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       119555793 213937604  94381812    45G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       213937668 423650114 209712447   100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       423650178 633362624 209712447   100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda9       633362688 843075134 209712447   100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda10      843075198 976768064 133692867  63.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda11       67121152 109064191  41943040    20G 83 Linux


Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4027580416 bytes, 7866368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa35ca2a2
```

I am new to Ubuntu.  I am using ubuntu16.04.  Now how to change it default boot partition.

The output of "journalctl -xb" is as follows
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvbRW.jpg)

Comment: What does journalctl -xb show? Usually there's a reason for entering single user mode, and without that reason, resolving it is nearly impossible.

Comment: I run the command "journalctl -xb" gives the output as follows pavan@pavan-desktop:~$ journalctl -xb
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

Comment: Run it from emergency mode... or (I don't remember if ubuntu stores journals by default) as root.

Comment: How can i come out from emergency mode?

Comment: Can you tell me why it has entered in to emergency mode? What I have to do now.

Comment: First find out *why* it has gone into emergency mode - using the suggested command.

Comment: I have taken image of the output of journalctl -xb command where it is in red color I think it is cause for the error is it sufficient .The image is above.